# Validar input con jQuery y expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC5, e intentando validar un input con jQuery y expresiones regulares. Lo que intento es que en el input sólo ingresen letras incluyendo la `'ñ'` y vocales con tilde.

Código:

```
$('#RazonSocial').on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (!/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]*$/.test(e.target.value)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

El problema de este código es que cuando ingreso dígitos y presiono un espacio, ya no deja ingresar más dígitos; y cuando presiono un número me muestra el primer número que digité.

Comment: Entonces, ¿debería aceptar números y espacios?

Comment: @Mariano, A si es

Answer (score 3):

Al intentar validar en el evento [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/keypress), no se valida:

- Cuando se pega texto
- En muchos navegadores mobile

Incluso, impedir la entrada de ciertos caracteres solía ser algo del pasado. Hoy en día, se suele dejar ingresar cualquier caracter y validar en el evento [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur), o al momento de enviar el formulario.

Pero siguiendo tu idea, podríamos validar en el evento [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/input). Este código elimina todo aquel caracter que no sea alfanumérico o espacio:

```js
$('#RazonSocial').on('input', function (e) {
    if (!/^[ a-z0-9áéíóúüñ]*$/i.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^ a-z0-9áéíóúüñ]+/ig,"");
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="RazonSocial">
```

---

Alternativamente, podríamos usar [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

```js
$(function() {
  
    $.validator.addMethod("alfanumOespacio", function(value, element) {
        return /^[ a-z0-9áéíóúüñ]*$/i.test(value);
    }, "Ingrese sólo letras, números o espacios.");
    
    $('#formulario').validate({
        rules: {
            RazonSocial: {
                alfanumOespacio: true,
                required: true,
            }
        }
    });
  
  
    //Para probar qué haría en el envío del form
    $('#probar').on('click', function(){
        console.log('Válido:',$('#formulario').valid());
    });
  
    
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Validation Plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<form id="formulario">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="RazonSocial">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="probar" value="Probar">
    </div>
</form>
```